# security check in matlab

Tags: authentication, matlab, ip

I've finished a matlab GUI development.
Now the distribution is under discussion.
Concerning the security, we want to have a authentication prior to running the GUI, to see if the user is in the valid network. Our first proposal is to check network domain/user account as an option.
How can it be achieved with matlab?

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this kind of informations with [`getenv`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/getenv.html), `winqueryreg` and maybe `system` and `hostid`. More generally see [Operating System Interface](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/f16-11063.html#f16-48001).